# BigQuery Error In where Clause with a String type column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column that contains strings like this '0 0PAA01 CF101 -S07'. I have some records in the database and when I tried to retrieve it using BigQuery the query is not returning records.
I am doing
select *
from table 
where column='0 0PAA01 CF101 -S07'

Is a BigQuery Problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure this is not a BigQuery problem - but that the strings are in fact different.

Look at this:

```sql
SELECT MD5('my name is Felipe Hoffa') from_keyboard
  , MD5(str) from_db
  , str='my name is Felipe Hoffa' equal_are_they
FROM (
     SELECT 'my name is Felipe Hoffa' str 
)
```

[image]

Why are they different? One has a tab instead of a space.